# At what $ω$ would the dust particles fly off the tilted rotating disc?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction

I've been struggling with question below:

> "*A metal disc of radius R can rotate about the vertical axis passing through its centre. The top surface of the disc is uniformly  covered with dust particles. The axis of the disc is tilted slightly to make an angle θ with the vertical. The disc is rotated with gradually increasing speed. At what value of angular speed (ω) of the disc the 75% of the top surface will become dust free. Assume the coefficient of friction between the dust particles and the disc (μ) is 0.5. Assume no interaction between dust particles.*

So I decided to check the solution.
In the solution, the author assumes that the dust particles fall off symmetrically( as if the disc is horizontal ) and what remains at the equilibrium are the dust particles making a circle of radius R/2 (Notice that it is same as if the disc is horizontal).

I don't seem to agree with it. I believe the dust particles wouldn't fall off symmetrically and at the equilibrium, we would get a somewhat different shape than a circle (i think, identical to an ellipse). The reason I say this because if the disc is tilted, in the lower part, centrifugal force (frame of reference: disc) would favour the component of weight and in the upper part centrifugal force would kinda oppose. Therefore, in the lower part dust particles would fall off more quickly as compared to upper part.

(By "equilibrium", I mean the time period after the dust particles are at rest (no more flying off ).)

Edit: I would like to add my take on this question,
[image]
If you consider an arbitrary point P such that it is about to fall, it's equation should be:
$$ μmgcosθ = √(m^2g^2sinθ + m^2ω^4x^2 + 2(mgsinθ)(mω^2x)cosΦ) $$

I don't know where to approach further.

Comment: Don't use images for text.

Comment: How would this problem be doable unless we knew something about the density of the dust, it seems we would need to know this in order to equate the centrifugal force to the static friction?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus eventually the mass 'm' would cancel out, ig

Comment: anyway, i am just asking if my thinking about this question is correct or not

Comment: @PinkAura I think the dust would leave off in a circular pattern regardless of whether or not the disc was inclined. The only factors that effect the dust in any case is the gravitational force and centrifugal force, if the disc was inclined, the radius of the dust left over would be smaller than if it were not inclined (dust would need to overcome static friction and gravitational component), however, the equilibrium condition would still exhibit radial symmetry; as the centrifugal force would be the same at any radial distance from the center.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus If the disc is inclined, Centrifugal force would favour the gravitational force in the lower part and in the upper part it would kinda oppose.

Comment: @PinkAura You are undoubtedly correct in that assessment; not sure what I was thinking to say such a thing!

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus Yes, I am just waiting for it to reopen and a proper answer to be posted... I don't get a reason why it was closed. any suggested edit?

Comment: @PinkAura They have really been cracking down lately on post that some regard as too much like a homework or check my work problem. Try to explain exactly what you think and ask about the *principles* that apply rather than solutions; its probably not a good idea to ask "am I right"; as this will be seen as check my work.

Comment: I agree with your assessment. If you take an extreme case with high angle and arbitrarily low coefficient of friction, dust just slides off the bottom edge at arbitrarily low rotation speed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your analysis is correct. The equation is indeed:
$$μmgcosθ=[(m²g²sin²θ + m²ω⁴x²+ 2(mgsinθ)(mω²x)cosΦ)]^.5   (1)$$

Since $θ$ is small you can approximate the equation to be
$$μmg=(m²ω⁴x²)^.5$$
You can neglect the force of mgsin$θ$ on any particle because $θ$ is arbitrarily small. So, you can indeed treat them like they all fall off circularly. (the particles at the outer edge falling first) Solving the question with this approximation will lead to the limiting value of $ω$ for which the particles at a distance of R/2 just fall off. **EDIT:** If they were to fall circularly then the conditions are:

$$mgsinθ + mω²x = μmgcosθ$$(x : limiting distance)
$$mw²(x+dx)>mgsinθ+μmgcosθ$$ dx tends to zero
$$2gsinθ/ω²  < dx$$

Comment: The equations you write are not completely true for *all the points of the two halves*, rather particular two points on the disc. 

Also, there is a slight correction, the disc is being rotated about its axis which is tilted, not the vertical axis.

If θ is 90 degrees (tend to), well, you wouldn't need any rotation at all to make the disc dust free, they would fall off by themselves.

Comment: Most importantly, you cannot assume for the upper half , when the dust particle is about to fall, it is at same distance x

Comment: umm... is it allowed to edit whole of your answer like you did? idk... anyway, in the question it is not stated that $θ$ is very small. in-fact in the solution, the author himself doesn't consider it to be small.